# view other website source code with javascript use in own site

Tags: javascript

I want to view other website source code with javascript use in my own website, i have a code, it's showing same window, i want to view other website source code, please help me i am new programmer.
Example i want show example.com to my website as source code.

```js
function viewSource(){;
    var source = "<html>";
    source += document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTMLz;
    source += "</html>";
    source = source.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    source = "<pre>"+source+"</pre>";
    sourceWindow = window.open('','Source of page','height=800,width=800,scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
    sourceWindow.document.write(source);
    sourceWindow.document.close(); 
    if(window.focus) sourceWindow.focus();
}
```

```html
<button type ="button" onclick="viewSource()">View Source</button>
```

Comment: Basically, you would like to scrap the page and then use the scrapped data ... a lot is written about that ... search for tutorials such as this: https://medium.com/data-scraper-tips-tricks/scraping-data-with-javascript-in-3-minutes-8a7cf8275b31

Comment: need to use something like tampermonkey or greasemonkey

Comment: i just need view other website source code in my website. that the java-script code i need. thank you

Comment: @Emocuc scrap and scrape mean two very different things

Comment: @Graeme Chapman - OK, sorry about the missing 'e' ...

Comment: @Shimanto Neer - you just need to get the code and then use it ... that is scraping ... be aware, the source, unless you wrote it or purchased it or does not explicitly state some sharing licence, the source is not yours and might be illegal to use on your page, basically, scraping is blackhat practice.

Comment: @Emocuc i just need for something to check.

Comment: You won't be able to do so purely with JavaScript due to the same origin policy restricting AJAX requests to your own domain. You would need to set-up a web-proxy at your own domain or rely on a third-party service (which provides CORS headers)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try an AJAX request:

```
function viewSource() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "someURL.com", true);
  request.send(null);
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4)
      alert(request.responseText);
  };
}
```

This would send a GET request for the document at the URL, which should be the page source. Just be aware of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: I think you're probably running into a CORS issue. One workaround is to use a proxy like cors.io, but this goes beyond the scope of your question. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joukpL3w/) for a working example of this using Google.

Comment: #AndroidNoobie Thanks for your help.